# Как в setObjectName добавить последовательное число?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt5, gui, pyqt

Я создаю **`каждый раз при нажатии кнопки`** `groupbox`

```py
def new(self):

    self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
    self.groupBox_2.setMinimumSize(QSize(411, 251))
    self.groupBox_2.setMaximumSize(QSize(411, 251))
    self.groupBox_2.setCheckable(False)
    self.groupBox_2.setStyleSheet(
        "border: 2px solid #FDD2BF;"
        "border-radius: 10;")

    self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_2")
```

Как мне в `setObjectName` добавить переменную, которая будет увеличиваться на один?

Внизу написал как я себе это представляю, но как вы понимаете это не работает.

```py
x += 1
...
self.groupBox_2.setObjectName("groupBox_{x}")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам действительно нужна помощь - опубликуйте
минимально-воспроизводимый пример.
Я вижу, что вы не правильно реализуете какую-то свою идею.

Сделать можно все, но поймите, что в цикле или как вы
пишите 
**`'каждый раз при нажатии кнопки'`** 
не делают экземпляр `QGroupBox` объектом класса

```
vvvv <--------------------- нет !!!
self.groupBox_2 = QGroupBox(self.scrollAreaWidgetContents)
```

я бы попробовал вам помочь, но вы почему-то упрямо не публикуете код.

А пока вот вам ответ на ваш вопрос,
но помните, что использовать где-то в логике так:

```
self.groupBox_2.оbjectName()
```

у вас не получится, потому что там будет всегда последнее значение.

---

```
...
class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.x = 0
    ...
    
    def new(self):
        self.x += 1
        self.groupBox_2.setObjectName(f"groupBox_{self.x}")
...
```